# Obtaining contiguity matrix from layer of polygons using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arctoolbox, distance-matrix

I have a layer of statistical areas, and would like to obtain the contiguity matrix, that is, the matrix W in which an entry w_ij equals 1 if i and j are neighbors (share a border) and 0 otherwise.

There must be some simple tool to do this in ArcGIS, but I could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool to do this is [Polygon Neighbors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/polygon-neighbors.htm) which:

> Creates a table with statistics based on polygon contiguity (overlaps,
>   coincident edges, or nodes).